# No fixture named 'X' found

Tags: django, django-south

I'm using Django 1.6 and I use South to handle migrations. 
In most of my application I used to have `initial_data.json` files. I converted them to be loaded with migrations rather than automatically by Django (as this is recommended in the documentation)

I was using version 0.8.2 of South when I ran into a weird behavior / bug where loading fixtures is done according to the model code and not the state of the migration. I saw that the newest version (0.8.4) has since added some bug fixes related to `loaddata`, so I upgraded to it.

Now I get the following error on all the migration that load fixtures:

```
UserWarning: No fixture named 'X' found.
```

When I use Django's `loaddata` it works fine. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you clarify "converted them to be loaded with migrations", what exactly you did with your fixtures?
Can you reproduce this problem on a fresh project?

Answer (score 9):

### [South and fixtures](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fixtures.html)

South simply patches syncdb to skip the fixture loading for models with migrations, and actually loads them after the final migration for an app has been run.

### Make sure your initial_data file is located in the correct place

Loading initial_data does not require you do actually do something, but place the fixtures in [the correct place as explained in Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

To quote the docs:

> By default, Django looks in the fixtures directory inside each app for
>   fixtures. You can set the FIXTURE_DIRS setting to a list of additional
>   directories where Django should look.

This means that if you have an app called "myapp", you'd create a "fixtures" dir inside it and place the json there, e.g.: `myproject/myapp/fixtures`.

### Django 1.7 and newer

Django 1.7 [introduced built-in migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/). These have an interface similar to South; management commands to create migrations `makemigrations`, run them `migrate`, and others.

However, `initial_data` fixtures are no longer auto-loaded on syncdb run; unless it is an existing app, and has no migrations. This is [mentioned in the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.7/#initial-data).

The docs now recomend to create a `datamigration` to handle fixture loading. Luckily, this is pretty easy to do, here's how I usually do it:

#### 1. create an [empty data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations --empty myapp
```

If you had only the initial migration, you end up with these files (note that I renamed migration 0002 for clarity):

```
myapp/
├── __init__.py
├── fixtures
│   └── my_initial_data.json
└── migrations
    ├── 0001_initial.py
    ├── 0002_load_fixture.py
    └── __init__.py
```

#### 2. update the code of `0002_load_fixture.py` to run loaddata

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations
from django.core.management import call_command


def load_my_initial_data(apps, schema_editor):
    call_command("loaddata", "my_initial_data.json")


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_my_initial_data),
    ]
```

Comment: yeah, in theory. I have a file called initial_data.json in a "fixtures" folder and have tried moving this folder to: `project_root`, `project_root/app_root`, `project_root/app_root/app` with no joy (Django 1.8 btw). Still getting this error every time i run the tests for the app.

Comment: ok, its a lie. Its really looking for one of: `initial_data[.default].[xml|yaml|json][.zip|.gz|.bz2]` in the **root project folder**. (p.s. I'm actually using Django 1.9)

Comment: So the documentation for 1.8 is wrong and the 1.7 note is also wrong as i'm using 1.9 and it still loads initial_data when you run tests?

Comment: It states here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/initial-data/ that "Django looks in the fixtures directory inside each app for fixtures". I found this was not the case and looked at the code and found (see above): "Its really looking for one of: initial_data[.default].[xml|yaml|json][.zip|.gz|.bz2] in the root project folder". Hence the documentation is _wrong_ and doesn't say what it actually does. You want me to ask: "Why is the Django docs wrong?"?

Comment: To whoever downvoted the answer, care to comment what is incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

This error also occurs when the filename does not include the '.json' extension.

In order to load a fixture from current working directory it has to end with '.json'.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run loaddata comand from your migration then?

```
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        from django.core.management import call_command
        call_command("loaddata", "my_fixture.json")
```

Comment: This fails for me also.

Answer (score 0):

If your still getting the error:

No fixture named 'X' found

Try using the path to the json file, as manage.py is probably not being run from the project directory (it may even be run from the root directory). Try something like this:

```
import os

app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
json_path = os.path.join(app_path, 'fixtures', 'my_fixture.json')
call_command("loaddata", json_path)
```